# no declaration can be found for element 'aws-context:context-region'

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

**application_context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aws/cloud/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context 
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

<aws-context:context-region region="us-west-2"/>

<aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
....</beans>
```

After compile, I got:

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 53; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aws-context:context-region'.
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the Spring people. They stopped maintaining this and they are using the schmea.handler. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-context/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.handlers

Answer (score 1):

Change from:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd

To:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd

but you can check if all your schemaLocations links return 200 ok before testing it. In case 404 you can find them individually under http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/

Comment: This is the first version I tried. Always got "no declaration can be found for element 'aws-context:context-region"

Comment: Looks like there is no attribute region for context-region element. Try using locationAttributeGroup instead.
<aws-context: locationAttributeGroup region="us-west-2"/>

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that "aws-context" is not allowed to combine with any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd">

  <aws-context:context-region region="us-west-2" />
<aws-context:context-credentials>
   <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="XXXXX" secret-key="XXXXXXX" />
  <aws-context:context-resource-loader />
</beans>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It even cannot find http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd

Comment: emm it's strange. I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you include other spring dependency except for spring-cloud-aws-context?